# Redirect to a "Thank you" page after hiting "send"

Tags: php, redirect

This will sound stupid but can you please tell me how to redirect people to a "Thank you" or "Please try again later" page in PHP after clicking "send" ?

I think it has something to do with adding something to the echo instead of the message I already added, to add the landing page or something like it but I just wanted to make sure, can you please help?

PHP code here:

```
function validateEmail($value){
    return preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $value);
}


if ( isset($_POST['last']) && $_POST['last']!="Nume" && isset($_POST['first']) && $_POST['first']!="Prenume" && isset($_POST['address']) && $_POST['address']!="Adresă" && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!="Email" && isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone']!="Telefon" && isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message']!="Ai întrebări legate de produse? Scrie-mi şi îţi voi răspunde în cel mai scurt timp." ) {

    if ( validateEmail($_POST['email']) ) {




        $destination="brilliancedisplay@outlook.com";

        $subject="Sunt ceva nelamuriri in magazin!";

        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Nume:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['last']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Prenume:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['first']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Adresa:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['address']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>E-mail:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['email']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Telefon:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['phone']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Intrebari:</strong></dt><dd>";  
        $mailMessage.=nl2br($_POST['message'])."</dd></dl>";
        $mailMessage = utf8_decode($mailMessage);




        $mailFrom=$_POST['email'];


        $mailHeader="From:".$mailFrom."\nReply-To:".$_POST['name']."<".$mailFrom.">\n"; 
        $mailHeader=$mailHeader."X-Mailer:PHP/".phpversion()."\n"; 
        $mailHeader=$mailHeader."Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
        $mailHeader=$mailHeader."Content-Type: text/html";

        if ( mail($destination,$subject,$mailMessage,$mailHeader) ) {
            echo 'Comanda trimisa!';
        }           
        else echo 'Eroare, va rugam incercati mai tarziu.';

    }       
    else echo 'Introduceti o adresa de Email valida';   //EMAIL VALIDATION ERROR

}
else echo 'Completati toate spatiile!';     //VARS ERROR
```

?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect is easy. Just use:

```
header('Location: page.php');
```

then replace page.php whit your own thanks page.

Answer (score 1):

Actualty, according to me, there is no need to redirect.
You can do the following:-

```
<?php
//your code
if(successful){
  echo "Thank you+ your design";
}
else
{
  echo "aww! snap..sumthin went wrong";
}
?>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
if(success)
{
header('Location: success.php');
}
else
{
header('Location: fail.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect to a new page. Create a separate 'thank you' page and use this URL in the 'location' value.